# How can I call a module from a hook - Prestashop 1.7

Tags: module, hook, prestashop-1.7

I have created a new module with template. I call my module and my template in my custom hook. It work fine. But I want to call another existing module in my custom hook and I don't want to override this module because if it's deleted my module will certainly crash. So there is a solution to call this existing module with my custom hook or it is simply impossible ?

I try too do this manually in the back office but it's work with "displayLeftColumn" and "displayRightColumn" but not with my custom hook.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a hacky workaround you're trying to do ;)

Well, you could do something like this inside your implementation of the custom hook:

```
$module = Module::getInstanceByName('somemodule');
$moduleHookResult = $module->hookDisplayRightColumn($params);
```

or you could do the following:

```
$moduleHookResult = Hook::exec('displayRightColumn', ['params' => $params], Module::getModuleIdByName($module_name));
```

Still, I'm not sure if that should be the final solution.